# How to let the command window open while executing command prompt scripts from C#?

Tags: c#, command-line

I am facing a strange issue. I have an application in which a method executes some of command prompt commands but they are not executing in an appropriate way. The code snippet looks like

```
private void encryptAndWrite(String FileName)
{
    string strEntry = FileName.Replace("\\web.config", ""); // Let the user assign to this string, for example like "C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\Test\Websites\AccountDeduplicationWeb"

    Process p = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };    
    p.Start();    
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319");
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis.exe -pc \"CustomKeys12\" -exp");
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis.exe -pa \"CustomKeys12\" \"NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE\"");
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis -pef \"connectionStrings\" {0} -prov \"CustomEncryptProvider\"",strEntry);
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis -px \"CustomKeys12\" {0} -pri",KeyFileName);

    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    Thread.Sleep(7000);
    updateTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
    updateTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
    updateMessageLabel.Text = String.Empty;
    showConfig(FileName);
}
```

Essentially the last command should overwrite a file which is supplied by

```
KeyFileName
```

each time the command executes successfully. But it is not.
If I hard code it like

```
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis -px \"CustomKeys12\" \"C:\\Users\\Chiranjib\\Desktop\\XMLKey\\CustomEncryptKey.xml\" -pri");
```

it executes successfully. 
So is there a way where I can let the command window open so that I can see where the commands are going wrong ? I though tried CreateNoWindow = false
but it does not show the command by command execution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you pretending to `cmd` that you're a user typing commands instead of just running those commands yourself?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using Process.Start()?

Comment: You really should be starting the `aspnet_regiis.exe` with the parameters, not cmd.exe and sending stuff to stdin.

Comment: @Anonymous .. I am using p.Start() right ?

Comment: @RonBeyer .. Could you please give me the solution with an example ?

Comment: @Joey .. I have to run them via app only . Sadly that's the requirement.